# how to push (input) multiple files to an array JQUERY

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I've been working on this problem for a long time, I haven't solved it yet. I'm trying to send the files I selected with some data to the controller, but I couldn't find how it was put into an array.

Here my jquery code

```
var data = [];
        $("div[data-id=siparisUrunleri]").each(function () {
            data.push({
                id: parseInt($(this).children().children("#data-id").text()),
                //.. some values

                resimler: $(this).children().children().children("input[data-id=imgEkle]").get(0).files // there is problem. If i put '[0]' the line , im taking first value. But i want to all files
            
           });
        });
```

Here my class

```
public class Order
    {
        ....
        public string plaka { get; set; }
        public List<SubPart2Val> parcalar { get; set; }
    }
```

sub class

```
public class SubPart2Val
    {
        ...
        public string  eksper { get; set; }
        public List<IFormFile> resimler { get; set; }

    }
```

dynamic html

```
var ic = "<div class='grid' name='marketproduct' data-id='siparisUrunleri' data-remove='" + data.id + "'>";
                ic += "<div class='grid-alan'>";
                ic += "<div class='grid-sutun-button'>&nbsp; </div>";
                ic += "<div class='grid-sutun-button' id='data-id' style='display:none'>" + data.id + "</div>";
                
                ic += "<div class='grid-sutun' id='resimler-ToTotal'><input type='file' multiple='multiple' data-id='imgEkle' id='panel-resim_"+id+"' hidden/></div>";
                ic += "<div class='grid-sutun'><input type='button' class='sepetten-cikar' onclick='remove(this)'  value='Çıkar'/></div></div></div>";
```

[image]

and there is problem.

[image]

Comment: Hi, show your html code as well

Comment: u can check now

Comment: see if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7ncag6jb/) works for you.